# Forcing redraw/repaint of a DOM element in firefox after page load

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I've looked through similar threads and tried everything that was suggested there to no avail.

I'm trying to replace an image after the page was loaded by changing it's src attribute once I have a new location. I want to replace the image with a local image.

Directly changing the src attribute via **img.src = urlString;** or using the **setAttribute()** method sets the src but doesn't redraw the image in the loaded page. I used **window.alert(img.src);** to check that the src attribute is really changed.

I've used the following code snippet from [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/javascript-snippet-force-dom-element-redrawrepaint/) to force a redraw.

```
var n = document.createTextNode(' ');
var disp = img.style.display;
img.appendChild(n);
img.style.display = 'none';

img.style.display = disp;
n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
```

Nothing seems to work. Is it because the page is loaded or is it because I am using a local file?

The local file is in *%AppData%\temp*, could this be a permission problem? The browser console doesn't throw any error. I do not want to refresh the entire page since someone could be typing in a form and they're going to lose their data.

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT : A bit of clarification.
I use an extension to inject a script in every window. Once a window loaded a page I send the images to another script for processing, the script then returns an event to the window with a location to a new file. Once the event is caught, a function is called to change the src attribute of a particular image. I've checked everything, the src is changed but the browser doesn't display the new image.

Another edit :
There doesn't seem to be a permission problem since I can access the file from the address bar using *file:///pathtofile/*. With external urls (e.g. *http://*) it seems to work even after page load. How can I make it work with local urls?

Comment: If that won't disrupt your document flow, you could remove the old image (by deleting it's DOM node), and replace it with the new one.

Comment: I can't be sure. I won't know what page I'm getting so I wouldn't know what kind of damage that will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does not allow untrusted pages to load data from `file://` URIs in any way.  That includes loading images from `file://` URIs.

To see why, consider what happens if a page does `<img src="file:///dev/tty">` on Linux or Mac, for example.  Similar issues exist on some Windows versions if you try to read from `file:///c:/con` and the like...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to use a web server to change the images.